# Binding ConverterParameter with control's one of property itself

Tags: data-binding, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I want to pass Rectangle's fill property as ConverterParameter on my Windows 8 app, how can I do this? My below effort is not working. The rectangle is a part of gridview's DataTemplate.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{Binding status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColor},ConverterParameter={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Fill}}" 
 Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<Rectangle x:Name="rect" Fill="{Binding status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToColor},ConverterParameter={Binding Fill,ElementName=rect}}" 
 Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Comment: After posting an answer, I noticed that you're trying to bind the rectangle's fill to its own fill -- this would cause an infinite loop.  What do you mean by this?

Comment: I need to set fill property according to fill property's previous value.

Comment: Right ... wither way, you will need to implement this logic in the view model or code-behind.  You can't bind a property to itself, it would cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind a dependency property to itself. You'll have to introduce another layer here, either:

- Using a view model that exposes the value you wish to bind to
- Using a `UserControl` or derived element type and introducing a new dependency property.